# comparing subtracting and printing using awk

Tags: awk, command

I have a file which looks like:

```
 4.97911047         1.00000000         631.000000         369.343907   
 4.98065923        0.999492004         632.000000         369.771568   
 5.70441060        0.480057937         974.000000         642.686561   
 5.70448527        0.479704863         975.000000         641.643578   
 8.23090986        0.310811710         2020.00000         331.182895   
 8.23096067        0.312290865         2021.00000         331.188128   
 14.8077297        0.357914635         3181.00000         449.390996   
 14.8077541        0.352977613         3180.00000         449.377675
```

I want to subtract the consecutive numbers in the first column. If the result is less than or equal to some threshold say modulus 0.01, it should print the corresponding data range in the 3rd column. 
For example, the difference in the 2nd and 1st consecutive data of the 1st column is

`4.98065923-4.97911047=0.00154876.`

Thus it should print

`"631-632"`

Then the difference in the 3rd and 2nd consecutive data of the 1st column is

`5.70441060-4.98065923=0.723751`

Thus it should not print anything. Again, the difference in the 4th and 3rd consecutive data of the 1st column is

`5.70448527-5.70441060=7.467e-05`

Thus it should print

`"974-975"...`

in this way. The final output should be like:\

```
631-632 \
974-975 \
2020-2021 \
3181-3180 \
```

Note: If the difference is less than 0.01 for 3 or more consecutive numbers of the 1st column, then it should also print the total range like "631-635" say.\

The best I could do until now is to use awk command and make the corresponding differences: \

`awk 'NR > 1 { print $0 - prev } { prev = $0 }'  < filename`

Any help?
Regards
Sitangshu

Comment: You should consider reading the `awk` manual. It is short and very well written. You will very quickly understand why `print $0 - prev` does not make sense in your case. And you will also learn that the first field is `$1`, the second `$2`...

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

I would GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
 4.97911047         1.00000000         631.000000         369.343907   
 4.98065923        0.999492004         632.000000         369.771568   
 5.70441060        0.480057937         974.000000         642.686561   
 5.70448527        0.479704863         975.000000         641.643578   
 8.23090986        0.310811710         2020.00000         331.182895   
 8.23096067        0.312290865         2021.00000         331.188128   
 14.8077297        0.357914635         3181.00000         449.390996   
 14.8077541        0.352977613         3180.00000         449.377675
```

then

```
awk 'NR>1&&($1-prev[1])<=0.01{printf "%d-%d\n",prev[3],$3}{split($0,prev)}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
631-632
974-975
2020-2021
3181-3180
```

Explanation: For each line I save under `prev` not whole line (string) but rather array, using [`split`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function to do so, so I can access for example 3rd field of previous line as `prev[3]`. For each line after 1st one and where difference between 1st field of current line and 1st field or previous line is lesser or equal `0.01` I do `printf` 3rd field of previous line and 3rd field of current line, using `%d` to get value formatted as integer.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*